# Missing contacts after switching phones even with the same SIM card

Tags: contacts, sim-card

I switch phones from a Samsung Galaxy II to Motorola Moto G and was able to use the same SIM card, but my contacts are gone.

How to recover them?

Answer (score 1):

They are not gone, they're just left on the old device. Contacts are no longer stored on the SIM card by default for years already. If you've synchronized them (e.g. with Google), you should be able to synchronize them back with the same service on your new device.

Otherwise, you'll have to export them on your old device, transfer the export to your new device, and import it again:

#### On the old device:

1. open *Contacts*
2. hit the *Menu* button (the 3 "stapled dots" in the upper right corner), and chose *Import/Export*
3. select to export them to your storage (SD card)
4. copy the exported file (usually `/sdcard/0001.vcf`) to the SD card of your new device

#### On the new device

1. open *Contacts*
2. hit the *Menu* button (the 3 "stapled dots" in the upper right corner), and chose *Import/Export*
3. select to import from storage (SD card)
4. select the file

Now your contacts should be there again.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the question you asking here is why your contacts didn't restore from your SIM card...

Most phones don't store contacts to SIM anymore... That is a practice in general from before smartphones. Today contacts are often stored with your online account such as Google account, Apple ID, or Microsoft account.

Many devices have a default location to store contacts, although most users your online account, some use a device only storage scheme, few actually store to the SIM card, and to my knowledge none do by default.

Try adding the same Google account used on your previous device to your new device... If that doesn't work, you will need to use the old device and export your contacts off so you can import them unto your new device or Google account.

Answer (score 0):

Open contact app on your mobile. On top right corner if you see mobile symbol then your contact are stored on mobile not sim card.
On new mobile you can save contact on device or on google account.

You can export contact. Open contact app / setting / export. Then import to new mobile.

On old mobile you have option to save contact on sim card or phone memory.